# How to inspect argument to a gmock EXPECT_CALL()?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, googlemock

I'm using Google Mock (gMock) for the first time. Given the following code snippet:

```
class LinkSignals
{
    public:
        virtual ~LinkSignals() { }

        virtual void onLink(std::string) = 0;
        virtual void onUnLink() = 0;
};


class MockLinkSignals : public LinkSignals
{
    public:
        MOCK_METHOD1(onLink, void(std::string));
        MOCK_METHOD0(onUnLink, void());
};
```

`MockLinkSignals mock_signals;`

When I execute some test code that causes `EXPECT_CALL(mock_signals, onLink(_))` to be run how can I inspect the argument to `onLink()`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You would normally use either existing gmock matchers or define your own to check the arguments passed to the mock method.

For example, using the default Eq equality matcher:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock_signals, onLink("value_I_expect"))
```

Or check for sub string say:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock_signals, onLink(HasSubstr("contains_this")))
```

The gmock documentation provides details of the standard matchers that are available, and also describes how to make custom matchers, for example for an integer argument type:

```
MATCHER(IsEven, "") { return (arg % 2) == 0; }
```

It is possible to capture an argument to a variable by attaching an action to the expectation, although this can have limited use in the scope of the expectation:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock_signals, onLink(_)).WillOnce(SaveArg<0>(pointer))
```

I'd suggest studying the various matchers and actions available before choosing the best approach for your particular case.

Comment: In this explanation what is pointer and what is `SaveArg<0>(pointer)`?

Comment: @Maf `pointer` is a pointer to the variable where the argument should be written to, e.g. `&myvariable` as destination for value of `SaveArg<0>`